# getFromLocationName returns few addresses or does not searches accurately

Tags: android

I am trying to use getFromLocationName but even if the MAX address is set to 30, it returns 1 or very few addresses. I tested it by entering a broad search also (entered Citi) but I got only 1 address which was irrelevant. I want to know if someone has faced this problem or if there is any bug with this function.